# Netem - how to delay packets sent to/received from some host

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

Let say that we have host `A`, and host `B`. We would like to use `netem` to simulate following scenario: `B` sends packets to `A` with some delay.
How to do it with `netem` in two scenarios:
(1) Running `netem` on host `A`
(2) Running `netem` on host `'B`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

There are several good sources for how to introduce delay on incoming and outgoing packets. [This NetEm wiki page](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem) as a lot of information. See section "1.1 Emulating wide area network delays" for delaying outgoing packets and "2.3 How can I use netem on incoming traffic?" for incoming packets.
I tried these on my setup and had no trouble making it work.

Base latency:

```
# netperf -H $my_ip -t TCP_RR -P 0 -- -r 64 -o RT_LATENCY
21.800
```

100ms delay only on client side (B):

```
# tc qdisc add dev $my_interface root netem delay 100ms
```

Result:

```
# netperf -H $my_ip -t TCP_RR -P 0 -- -r 64 -o RT_LATENCY
102184.355
```

100ms delay only on client side (A):

First, create an Intermediate Functional Block pseudo-device IFB (ethernet bridge would also work):

```
# modprobe ifb
# ip link set dev ifb0 up
```

Next, redirect all incoming traffic to go through the IFB device first:

```
# tc qdisc add dev $my_interface ingress
# tc filter add dev $my_interface parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match u32 0 0 flowid 1:1 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
```

Now just add delay to the IFB device's outgoing traffic, which is now the incoming traffic to my_interface:

```
# tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root netem delay 100ms
```

Result:

```
# netperf -H $my_ip -t TCP_RR -P 0 -- -r 64 -o RT_LATENCY
154442.238
```

Applying both results in:

```
# netperf -H $my_ip -t TCP_RR -P 0 -- -r 64 -o RT_LATENCY
333803.282
```

As you can see, the latency is more than the added 100ms (or 200ms in last example) + base latency. NetEm causes a delay in a specific place in the pipe, so the longer than expected latency might be a side effect if the delay.

Comment: Some extra latency can be produced by the additional initial ARP request done which gets also the same delay. With a ping, the first ping answer would take twice the time it takes for the second answer.