# Impairing ingress traffic with TC on Docker without using IFB

Tags: networking, docker, vpn, tc

my understanding of Linux networking is rudimentary, but I'm hoping someone can at least point me in the right direction.

A common technique for impairing ingress traffic with Linux Traffic Control is to use an [IFB](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/ifb) driver. However, I cannot use this technique on a Docker container as there is no IFB device in Docker. Its beyond my understanding why, but I believe it has to do with what a Docker container has access to [kernel wise](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456796/how-to-install-ifb-module-in-ububtu).

I saw that this technique [can be used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432925/netem-how-to-delay-packets-sent-to-received-from-some-host) with an [ethernet bridge](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/network_bridge) instead of IFB. If my understanding is correct, an ethernet bridge is a network connection between two machines, where incoming traffic is routed through one machine to another. This sounds to me much like how a Docker network bridge operates.

My idea is to bridge two Docker containers, and impair outgoing traffic from the first container to the second, which would have the effect of impairing ingress traffic on the second. Exactly the same technique as using IFB.

I think I could do something like connect my container to a VPN container, and impair the VPN with TC. But I don't need the tunnelling capabilities, and don't want to add unnecessary latency to the network.

Will this idea work, and is there a more minimal solution than using a VPN? Please correct me if my understanding isn't right. Thanks!